# how to remove invoiced column in sale orders odoo 17

Tags: user-interface, odoo, invoice, debug-mode, odoo-17

Community any one help me how i removed invoiced column using inherit view through Odoo UI
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the field `optional` attribute.

***Example:***

```
<record id="view_order_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">sale.order.form</field>
    <field name="model">sale.order</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']/tree/field[@name='qty_invoiced']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="optional"></attribute>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

To do it through the UI, Go to `Technical / User Interface / Views` and look for `sale.order.form` then add a line under `Inherited Views`

- Set a view name (`sale.order.form.inherit`)
- and set the `Architecture` to:

  ```
  <xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']/tree/field[@name='qty_invoiced']" position="attributes">
      <attribute name="optional"/>
  </xpath>
  ```

Comment: I'm not sure about the question, but i read "how to remove the column". But this answer is only removing the `optional` attribute. That will lead to the column always be shown. Not my definition of "removing a column" :D

Comment: I assumed that English wasn't his first language and answered the question based on the image.

Comment: definitely is not, but seems you can read his/her mind because your answer is already accepted :-P